# RoundButtonTemplate change Background and Icon Color on pressed state

Tags: button, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, controltemplate

I have a RoundButtonTemplate to get buttons like the Play and Pause button of the Music player.

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates"/>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="100">
                <Ellipse x:Name="ButtonBackground" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContent" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

If the button is pressed the Background of the button should change to the foreground color and the icon which is displayed through the ContentPresenter should change to the background color or gets transparency.

Changing the background of the button to the foreground color is easy, but I don't know how to change the color of the image within the ContentPresenter?

Comment: Why do you want to change the color of the image, do you think that could be possible, why not changing the image itself ?

Comment: For example, I want to set the button background to white and the image color to black or transparent. This is possible with an OpacityMask laying over the image but I don't know how to set it on a ContentPresenter or ContentControl

Comment: Why don't you just change the image itself, that would make it simpler

Comment: How should I change the images within the Template? If I change the image in my code background on event Tap or Hold then I must create an event handler for each button.

Comment: If the template is implicit for this instance, just add the images (for normal and pressed states) and toggle their visibility or opacity for their respective states. Or if they're xaml path vectors just change their fills on their respective state.

Comment: The image within the button is different for each button so I need to create different templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attached Properties to the rescue!

**Step 1:**

Create a static class that holds an attached property.

```
public static class Design
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlternateContentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AlternateContent", 
        typeof (object), 
        typeof (Design), 
        null
    );

    public static void SetAlternateContent(DependencyObject element, object value)
    {
        element.SetValue(AlternateContentProperty, value);
    }

    public static object GetAlternateContent(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(AlternateContentProperty);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Add the alternate content to your template in another `ContentPresenter`, which starts off collapsed. Then in your `Pressed` visual state, collapse the original content and show the alternate one.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate"
                    TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Background="Transparent"
            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContentAlternate">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="0.5" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="0.5" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="0.5" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates" />
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder"
                BorderBrush="White"
                BorderThickness="3"
                Background="Transparent"
                CornerRadius="100">
            <Ellipse x:Name="ButtonBackground"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </Border>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContent"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentAlternate"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Local:Design.AlternateContent}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Step 3:**

Any button that uses this template should provide two contents.

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Template="{StaticResource RoundButtonTemplate}">

    <Local:Design.AlternateContent>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red"
                    Height="40"
                    Width="40" />
    </Local:Design.AlternateContent>

    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow"
                Height="40"
                Width="40" />
</Button>
```

**That's it!**

I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for! Thank you

Comment: Excellent. By the way, you can use this technique for a lot of design elements. My static Design class has many of these properties reused in many templates. You can do some advanced UI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates"/>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="100">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ButtonBackground" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContent" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When pressed the Background of the buttons becomes of the color of the Foreground and the content modify it's opacity to 50%.

Oh, i've made a "Style" instead of a template, so, you can call it like...

Other option is to change the current VisualState Pressed, it's the only modification I've made.